# Range of radical function?

Tags: functions, radicals

The range of the radical function $y=(x+1)^{1/2}$ is $[0,∞)$. I know how to find it; however, when we solve for $x$ we find the range of $x=y^2-1$ is $[-1,∞)$. So, why do we have two different ranges?

Also, the function y=$x^{1/2}+1$ has a different range from $x=y^2-2y+1$. How is that range differs when we solve for $x$ in both cases?

Comment: y is the range, x is the domain

Comment: I know but when you solve for x you get the range.

Answer (score 0):

The range of the inverse function is the domain of the function.

Similarly, the range of the logarithmic function is $\mathbb{R}$, but its domain is $(0,\infty)$, which is the range of the exponential function.

Domain and range of a function are not related (except for the fact that they are specific of the given function, of course).

Comment: The domain of the inverse function, x=y^2-1, is all real numbers, but the range of y=(x+1)^1/2 is [0,∞) how is that possible?

Comment: @Yousif No, the inverse function of $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$ is the function $g(y)=y^2-1$ defined over $[0,\infty)$. The function $h(y)=y^2-1$ defined over the reals is not invertible, so it cannot be the inverse of $f$.